# Connect Visual Studio with remotely Cassandra server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cassandra, cql

I'm trying to connect Visual Studio C# code with a Cassandra server

The code works fine in localhost, but I want to connect code to make the change directly on the server. I found instructions to edit a cassandra.ymal file like

listen_address
or

start_rpc
or

rpc_address

Note:

- I open a Firewall on a specific port like 9042
- I used telnet command to test IP and port is open

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should **never** need to `start_rpc` anymore.  Assuming that your cassandra.yaml file is ok (can you also connect remotely with cqlsh?) check out DataStax's KillrVideo Cassandra project: https://github.com/luketillman/killrvideo-csharp

Comment: `rpc_address` is used to specify the address to listen on for client connections. You only need to set this to the IP address of the node (not 127.0.0.1) in order to connect via the network. You do not need to change `listen_address` - it is for inter-node communication, not client connections. `start_rpc` should always be false, as aaron pointed out. Setting this to true enables the legacy Thrift interface.

Comment: This question needs more clarity to be answerable or even just understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, i searched a lot, so i found this, that help me, hope it will help others. 
1 ) Install Cassandra Workbench  
2 ) Update `.cassandraWorkbench.jsonc` like below snippet

```
 //PasswordAuthenticator
{
    "name": "Cluster PasswordAuthenticator", // auth methods
    "contactPoints": ["xxx.xxx.xx.x", "xxx.xxx.xx.x"], // seed_provider -> seeds from your cassandra.yml
    "hosts": ["xxx.xxx.xx.x"], // your host address
    "authProvider": {
        "class": "PasswordAuthenticator",
        "username": "abc", // host username
        "password": "****" // host password
    }
}
```